# Removing Magicline Made Navigation Jumpy

Tags: css, wordpress, magicline

I just tried to remove the MagicLine that was built into my Wordpress theme by taking out the CSS code that I'll put below. It worked and the line is gone but now my navigation is all jumpy as you can see at the site: http://sheisbiddy.com/home/ Is there a better way to remove the line (I can't seem to find it in the piles of code that came with the theme) or anyway to get the menu back to normal? Thanks!

```
#navigation ul li#magic-line { position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100px; height: 4px; padding-left: 0; display: none; }
```

This is what is left for the navigation CSS:

```
#header {height: 100px; padding-top: 20px; margin: 0 auto; }

#logo { float:left; }

#logo { text-transform:capitalize; padding:35px 0; }    
#logo img { max-width:100%; }

#navigation {float:right;  margin-right:20px; }

#navigation ul { list-style:none; position:relative; }
#navigation ul li { float:left; padding-left:30px; font-size:12px; display:inline; position:relative; font-weight:bold; }

#navigation ul li a { color:#888; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:35px; display:inline; }  
#navigation ul li ul { position:absolute; border:1px solid #e9e9e9; display:none; left:15px; padding-bottom:15px; z-index:9999; }   
#navigation ul li ul li {  min-width:150px; margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; padding:15px 0 10px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #f6f6f6; font-weight:normal; font-size:10px; }  
#navigation ul li ul li:last-child {  border:0;  padding-bottom:0; }    
#navigation ul li ul li a { border:0; display:inline; padding:0; }  
#navigation li:hover ul { display:inline; }

#navigation select { display:none; -webkit-appearance: none; border-radius: 0; }
```

Comment: It is working !!, I can't see where's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an errors in you CSS which causes the navigation to behave this way...

in style.dynamic.php file :

Lines : 94,96,104

```
#tagline { background-color:; }
#navigation ul li { padding-bottom:px; }
#navigation ul li a { padding-top:px; }
```

Comment: I edited my question so you can see what the navigation is now

Comment: It's in the Style CSS under the Header section. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: check your navigation-border.js file, try commenting all the code inside the jQuery(document).ready(function() { .. });
I think that's what causes the weird behaviour of the navigation menu.

Comment: Which one is that? Sorry, I'm relatively new to this and finding anything buried in this theme is very difficult unless I know exactly what to search.

Comment: http://sheisbiddy.com/wp-content/themes/spacing/js/navigation-border.js?ver=4.3.1

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Now what do you mean by "commenting"?

Comment: Oh my goodness. That was such a stupid question. Sorry! Here: https://jsfiddle.net/t59LvL3g/   As far as I can tell, it's exactly the same.

Comment: I don't see that you commented the code inside Query(document).ready(function() { .. }); just copy and paste the code to your file : https://jsfiddle.net/9m4mrmty/

Comment: I thought I did. Weird. I don't know why it didn't do anything. It's working now! Thank you!!